# How to enable ws security in axis web service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, axis

I am new to web services and I need to implement ws security in an axis web service. I am not sure whether is it possible to add ws security to an existing web service without creating a new WSDL?

We are using spring and axis and exposing some admin methods which are being used by CSR admin's by a web browser, here is the server-config.wsdd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment name="administration" xmlns="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/providers/java">

    <globalConfiguration>
        <parameter name="adminPassword" value="admin"/>
        <parameter name="enableNamespacePrefixOptimization" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="attachments.Directory" value="C:\temp"/>
        <parameter name="disablePrettyXML" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="sendMultiRefs" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="sendXsiTypes" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="attachments.implementation" value="org.apache.axis.attachments.AttachmentsImpl"/>
        <parameter name="sendXMLDeclaration" value="true"/>
        <parameter name="axis.disableServiceList" value="true"/>
    </globalConfiguration>

    <handler name="LocalResponder" type="java:org.apache.axis.transport.local.LocalResponder"/>
    <handler name="URLMapper" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper"/>
    <handler name="Authenticate" type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.SimpleAuthenticationHandler"/>

    <service name="AdministrationRemoteServiceV490" provider="java:RPC" style="wrapped" use="literal" >
      <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="register, updateAccountUser, updateChannel, deleteAccountUser, addChannel" />
      <parameter name="className" value="com.abc.administration.soap.AdministrationRemoteServiceV490"/>
      <namespace>urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.9.0</namespace>

      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v470.EnquiryAccountUser" qname="admin:EnquiryAccountUser" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v460.EnquiryBankCard" qname="admin:EnquiryBankCard" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v490.EnquiryChannel" qname="admin:EnquiryChannel" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.9.0"/>     
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v490.EnquiryInformationImpl" qname="admin:EnquiryInformationImpl" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.9.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v490.EnquiryInformationListImpl" qname="admin:EnquiryInformationListImpl" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.9.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v490.SendSMSResponseImpl" qname="admin:SendSMSResponseImp" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.9.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.EnquiryAccountUser" qname="admin:MessageHistoryAccountUser" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.EnquiryMessage" qname="admin:EnquiryMessage" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.6.5"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.EnquiryMessageParameter" qname="admin:EnquiryMessageParameter" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.EnquiryeleIdentifier" qname="admin:EnquiryeleIdentifier" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.6.5"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v465.MessageHistoryListImpl" qname="admin:MessageHistoryListImpl" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.6.5"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.MessageHistoryImpl" qname="admin:MessageHistoryData" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v470.RegisterResponseImpl" qname="admin:RegisterResponseData" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v470.DeleteAccountResponseImpl" qname="admin:DeleteAccountResponseData" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v470.UpdateAccountUserResponseImpl" qname="admin:UpdateAccountUserResponseData" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v460.SupportedBrandingGroupsImpl" qname="admin:SupportedBrandingGroupsForSMS" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.data.impl.v460.MinimalBrandingGroup" qname="admin:BrandingGroup" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>

      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.service.exception.AccountUserException" qname="admin:AccountUserException" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.service.exception.BankCardException" qname="admin:BankCardException" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.service.exception.ChannelException" qname="admin:ChannelException" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.service.exception.DateException" qname="admin:DateException" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.framework.exception.ServiceException" qname="admin:ServiceException" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0"/>

      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.framework.exception.SystemException" qname="admin:SystemException" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0" />
      <beanMapping type="java:com.abc.administration.service.exception.BrandingGroupException" qname="admin:BrandingGroupException" xmlns:admin="urn:reg:ele:administration:soap:4.7.0" />
   </service>  


    <service name="AdminService" provider="java:MSG">
        <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="AdminService"/>
        <parameter name="enableRemoteAdmin" value="false"/>
        <parameter name="className" value="org.apache.axis.utils.Admin"/>
        <namespace>http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/</namespace>
        <namespace>http://xml.apache.org/axis/wsdd/</namespace>
    </service>

    <service name="Version" provider="java:RPC">
        <parameter name="allowedMethods" value="getVersion"/>
        <parameter name="className" value="org.apache.axis.Version"/>
    </service>

    <transport name="http">
        <requestFlow>
            <handler type="URLMapper"/>
            <handler type="java:org.apache.axis.handlers.http.HTTPAuthHandler"/>
        </requestFlow>

        <parameter name="qs:list" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSListHandler"/>
        <parameter name="qs:wsdl" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler"/>
        <parameter name="qs.list" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSListHandler"/>
        <parameter name="qs.method" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSMethodHandler"/>
        <parameter name="qs:method" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSMethodHandler"/>
        <parameter name="qs.wsdl" value="org.apache.axis.transport.http.QSWSDLHandler"/>
    </transport>

    <transport name="local">
        <responseFlow>
        <handler type="LocalResponder"/>
        </responseFlow>
    </transport>

</deployment>
```

Can somebody help how can I add ws security to this web service, it seems that this file creates wsdl file but not sure but checked other classes in the modules but couldn't find references of web service all other are java classes.